# Adding a dictionary in different language and enabling spellchecking for that language too?

Tags: dictionary, spellcheck

I always install the system with English and have no idea how to add a Spanish dictionary and spellchecking on my mac, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the language for spellcheck in system preferences > keyboard > text > spelling, and at the app level in Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Show Spelling and Grammar.

Some non-Apple apps, like MS Office, have their own internal settings for this function.

You set your preferred reference dictionaries in Applications > Dictionary > Preferences.

Comment: I have set `system preferences > keyboard > text > spelling` to "automatic by language", tried on TextEdit and it started to autocorrect spelling as soon as I typed a few words in Spanish. Also added a Spanish dictionary on the Dictionary app and it says downloading on the new tab for Spanish, I'll check it latter.